# По нажатию клавиши задача выполняется прерываниями UNITY3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пишу код, возникла проблема, когда нужно переместить персонажа на 1 таил я нажимаю кнопку пробел один раз, и он лишь немного меняет положение,  как исправить чтобы по нажатию он сделал передвижение полностью?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour {

    public float MoveSpeed = 1.5f;
    public int RotateStage = 0;



    private void Update() {
        Vector3 To;
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)){
            if(RotateStage <= 2){ RotateStage = RotateStage + 1; }else{ RotateStage = RotateStage = 0; }
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){
            if(RotateStage >= 1){ RotateStage = RotateStage - 1; }else{ RotateStage = RotateStage = 3; }
        }



        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
            
            To = transform.position;

            if(RotateStage == 0){
                To.x = To.x + 1;

        
            }
            if(RotateStage == 1){
                To.y = To.y + 1;


            }
            if(RotateStage == 2){
                To.x = To.x - 1;

                
            }
            if(RotateStage == 3){
                To.y = To.y - 1;
            
                
            }
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, To, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            To.x = 0; To.y = 0;
        }
        





    }
}
```

Comment: возможно дело в том что ты все ифы подряд поставил а не иф - елс иф - елс иф - елс иф - елс

Comment: `Пишу код`, конечно, сильно сказано. В строке `To.x = To.x + 1;` и ее дубликатах вы просто прибавляете 1 к своей позиции, а затем, при помощи линейной интерполяции делаете эту единицу еще меньше. Соответственно перемещаетесь не на 1 тайл, а на 0,064682 метра. Думаю, по запросу: `unity тайлы гайд` в youtube вы найдете достаточно информации по тайлам

Comment: @KOTlK - Неспорю, но щас я имелл ввиду что я неистово долблю по пробелу чтобы передвинуть обьект, когда нужно нажать 1 раз для ПЛАВНОГО перемещения в сторону

Comment: Вы пытаетесь достичь плавности путем телепортации объекта, используйте физическое движение. Можете попробовать использовать корутину, которая будет перемещать объект на определенную дистанцию в определенном направлении.

Answer (score 0):

Изначально у тебя не правильный подход, ты с помощью if уже меняешь позицию объекта, так как To = transform.position.
Создай приватное поле Vector3 и задавай уже ему все что тебе хочется.

```
private Vector3 to;

private void Start(){
   to = transform.position;
}

private void Update(){
   if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
        if(RotateStage == 0){
            To.x = To.x + 1;
        }
        if(RotateStage == 1){
            To.y = To.y + 1;
        }
        if(RotateStage == 2){
            To.x = To.x - 1;
        }
        if(RotateStage == 3){
            To.y = To.y - 1;
        }
    }
    
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, To, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```